# disable ubuntu 10.10 screensaver using command

Tags: screensaver, ubuntu-10.10

Does anyone know how to disable ubuntu 10.10 screensaver by just using command or edit conf?
because I can only ssh to the machine to turn the screensaver off
thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable the screensaver:

```
gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled --type=bool false
```

To disable monitor sleeping:

```
gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/timeout/sleep_display_ac --type=int 0
```

Comment: I dont hv /apps this folder.. I am just using the ubuntu10.10 original screensaver (or I should say the lock screen?), sorry, because I am new in ubuntu

Comment: I tried to type gconf-editor in cmd, there are 
/apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled  and
/apps/gnome-power-manager/    
I have just made the changes, now checking if it works!~
Thx!

Comment: The command to disable monitor sleeping has changed. 
gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/timeout/sleep_display_ac --type=int 0 

refer to the answer below by @Nioasulul

Answer (score 0):

The command to disable monitor sleeping has changed. You should now run:

`gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/timeout/sleep_display_ac --type=int 0`

Comment: This would have been better as a comment on the accepted question.